# What about the vibrations/rotations of molecules that don't absorb light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy

We tend to talk about transitions between the different rotational and vibrational states, always in the context of spectroscopy, with It's own rules like: "in order for the IR vibrational transition to occur there must be a change in electric dipole moment" or "for this transition to be raman scattering there must be a change in polarizibility", and so on.

And I ask: what about the molecules that don't fullfill these requeriments to interact with light? Do they naturally vibrate/rotate by thermal excitation with no problems? Let's take an example: a typical spherical top molecule, the methane. It is inactive both in Raman and Infrared. If the methane gas has the required energy (a sufficient high temperature to activate the modes) then there will be a typical distribution of energy levels of the modes across the various molecules, in the same way that is for spectroscopy actives coumpounds? In other words: the fact that a molecule is spectroscopically inactive, make It less effective in doing non radiative transitions?

Answer (score 0):

Collisions are a very effective way of exciting and de-exciting vibrational states. Indeed we generally use low pressures when recording spectra from gases precisely to reduce the collision frequency. If the pressures are too high we get [collision quenching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quenching_(fluorescence)#Collisional_quenching). At lower pressures we may still see spectra but with broadened lines due to the reduction in lifetime due to the collisions.

So the answer to your question is that the lack of radiative absorption or emission has little to no effect on the excitation of vibrational states, except possible in extreme cases where collisions are very infrequent.